# Gallery View not filling complete screen when get created

Tags: android, view, position, gallery

I have created horizontal gallery view using this [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) 
But when gallery is created it starts from half of the screen, below screen shot

[image]

I want that when gallery view starts it should start from left of screen not center.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better way to escape, mark the focus from second item.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in xml--

android:gravity="left"

Answer (score 0):

in your `getView` function you can set the image that should be centered. So you can set the last image as below

```
imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
```

Something I did

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

return imageView;
}
```